# tcolorbox `interior titled code app` does not work

Tags: tcolorbox

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,hooks}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{enhanced,
frame code app={\draw[yellow,line width=1cm] (frame.south west)--(frame.north east);},
interior titled code app={\draw[red,line width=1cm] (frame.north west)--(frame.south east);},
leftrule=3mm,
arc=4mm,
colframe=blue!80!red,colback=white,colbacktitle=blue!5!yellow!50!white,
fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
boxed title style={enhanced,boxrule=.5mm,frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)-- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)-- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west) -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)-- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west) -- cycle;}  },
title={#2},#1}


\newtcolorbox{mybox2}[2][]{enhanced,
    frame code app={\draw[yellow,line width=1cm] (frame.south west)--(frame.north east);},
    interior titled code app={\draw[red,line width=1cm] (frame.north west)--(frame.south east);},
    leftrule=3mm,
    arc=4mm,
    colframe=blue!80!red,colback=white,colbacktitle=blue!5!yellow!50!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black,
%   attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2}, 
    boxed title style={enhanced,boxrule=.5mm,frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)-- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)-- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west) -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)-- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west) -- cycle;}  },
    title={#2},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{Studied systems}
    \lipsum[1]  
\end{mybox}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{mybox2}{Studied systems2}
    \lipsum[1]  
\end{mybox2}

\end{document}
```

It gives:
[image]

I want to have red line crossing first tcolorbox as well. I found out that `attach boxed title to top center` code make an effect that red line disappears.

What it the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `frame code app` and `interior titled code app` are quite low-level options. `interior titled code app` adds code for drawing the interior of a box with a title. All *boxed title* versions detach the title from the main box and put it into an own box. This means, that the main box is to be considered as a box without title. Therefore, `interior titled code app` has no effect, because it is only used for the titled box (in a low-level sense).

One possible solution is to replace `interior titled code app` by `interior code app`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,hooks}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{enhanced,
  frame code app={\draw[yellow,line width=1cm] (frame.south west)--(frame.north east);},
  interior code app={\draw[red,line width=1cm] (frame.north west)--(frame.south east);},
  leftrule=3mm,
  arc=4mm,
  colframe=blue!80!red,colback=white,colbacktitle=blue!5!yellow!50!white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black,
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  boxed title style={enhanced,boxrule=.5mm,frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)-- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)-- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west) -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)-- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west) -- cycle;}  },
  title={#2},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{Studied systems}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Alternatively, since the red line crossing is on top of the box, you could use `overlay` or `underlay` options which are more high-level and work independent from title settings.